# Create comment form dynamically with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to create a form that will pop up, allow the user to type in a comment, drag their comment to where they want it to stick, and then be able to save. I want to save what they write, the x/y coordinates of where they dropped it, and the height/width of it.

I am still pretty new to programming so I'm not sure the best way to go about this. I'd like to create and send the form with AJAX so the user doesn't have to leave the page.

Right now, I am storing the form's html in a jquery variable that is called when the user wants to comment. Is there a better way to do this? I am pretty lost and need help!!

It may be easier to understand if you take a look at my JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vickera/8vpf2qzu/5/

```
$("#add_text").click(function () {
    var add_text_form = '<div class="draggable" id="drag"><form action="submit_form.php"><textarea name="text"></textarea><br><span id="post_info"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></form><div>';

    $('#content').append(add_text_form); //Here I'd like to add/send a form via AJAX, I think...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your click handler to

```
$("#add_text").click(function () {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();
    var id = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    id += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    var $add_text_form = $('<div />', {
        id: id,
        class: 'draggable'
    });

    var $post_info = $('<span />', {
        id: "post_info" + id
    });

    var $text_area = $('<textarea />', {
        name: 'text'
    }).val('Share your thoughts...');

    var $form = $('<form />').append($text_area).append($('<br />')).append($post_info).append($('<input />', {
        type: 'submit',
        class: 'button'
    }).val('Submit'));

    $add_text_form.append($form);

    $('#content').append($add_text_form);

    $add_text_form.draggable({
        containment: "parent",
        cursorAt: {
            top: 20,
            left: 80
        }
    });

    $add_text_form.css("top", top, "left", "100px");

    $add_text_form.hover(function () {
        $post_info.delay(800).show();
    }, function () {
        $post_info.hide();
    });

    $form.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url, //replace this with your url
            data: {
                comment_x: $text_area.offset().left,
                comment_y: $text_area.offset().top,
                comment_height: $text_area.height(),
                comment_width: $text_area.width(),
                comment: $text_area.val()
            },
            success: function () {
                //when the ajax post is successful
            },
            dataType: dataType //the datatype you are expecting the server to return
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vpf2qzu/10/

Change the commented lines to your values and you should be posting the correct values